# Highcharts - Hide category of stacked column with visible total of 0

Tags: javascript, sorting, highcharts, hide, stacked-chart

I have a stacked column chart with 4 series making up each column on the X-axis. When clicking the legend to hide a series, many columns may then total to 0.

I can not figure out how to hide these columns.

**All Series Being Shown**
[Screenshot of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbbNh.png)

**Main Series Being Hidden**
[Largest Series Hidden Resulting in 0's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoHNq.png)

As you can see, the X-axis is not resizing to make only columns with non 0 totals show.
I have tried a variety of things that others have mentioned.

The code I am working from is:

```
Highcharts.chart(containerName, {
chart: {

     marginTop : 100,
    marginBottom : 130,
    //marginleft : 30,
    //marginright : 30,
    spacingTop: 10,
    borderColor: '#335cad',
    borderWidth: 4,
    type: 'column',
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontWeight : 'normal',
    }
},
title: {
    text: title
},
xAxis: {
    categories: nkeys,
    title: {
                text: xtitle,
                fonts : 'Arial',
                fontSize : '20px'
               
            },
            style: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontWeight : 'normal',
    },
    labels: {
        rotation: 300
    }
     
},
yAxis: {
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontWeight : 'normal',
        strokewidth:'0px',
    },
    textShadow: false,
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Count'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        strokewidth:'0px',
        style: {
            //fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            textoutline : '0px contrast',
            
            color: ( // theme
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
            ) || 'gray'
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -333,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 30,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor:
        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false,
    itemStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontFamily: 'arial'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
},
// Formatting of the Chart
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        
        stacking: 'normal',
        strokewidth:'0px',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
            return this.y > 0 ? '<p style="font-family:Arial;stroke-width:0px">' + this.y + '</p>' : null;
        },
            textshadow : false,
            enabled: true,
            strokewidth:'0px',
            style: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontWeight : 'normal',
        textshadow : false,
        strokewidth:'0px',
        textoutline : false 
    }
          
        }
    }
}, //Data to be displayed 
series: [{
    name: 'WO Complete',
    data: anwnValue,
    color : '#fc8eac',
    legendIndex : 1,
    strokeWidth : "0px",
    borderColor : '#000000',

    style: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        strokewidth:'0px',
        borderWidth :'0px',
        fontWeight : 'normal'
    }

},{
    name: 'Needs Work',
    data: nwvalue,
    color : '#FF0000',
    legendIndex : 0,
    borderColor : '#000000',
}, {
    name: 'Abnormal',
    data: anvalue,
    color : '#FFBF00',
    legendIndex : -1,
    borderColor : '#000000',
}, {
    name: 'Normal',
    data: nvalue,
    color : '#32CD32',
    legendIndex : -2,
    borderColor : '#000000',
}]
```

});

Comment: Check [this highcharts forum post](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37522) - especially this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/q9mve1ax/) - you'll see the formatter already hides the labels in the axis - "change the `bar` for `colum` type chart".

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel The code referenced by Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes is a good example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/q9mve1ax/
Hiding the data labels is one thing, but how do you hide an empty column. i.e. if you have the 4th column empty, the data label won't show, but the column will still remain

Comment: `but the column will still remain` - how the 0 value should be represented as a column on the chart?

Comment: It would not be. If a column would be empty, or have a total of 0, after it has been hidden by the legend, the column itself would not be shown. In the example, once John and Joe are hidden, the "Bananas" column would not be included in the chart until one of those two series was shown again.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you want to have the same behaviour as exists if this point is not defined: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ezwvxLt6/ I am afraid that you will need to implement your own custom logic to achieve that because as you can see, this point is attached to the data anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pftdka9b/